# Searching a has_many :through association including the middle model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, join, model-associations

First, the topic.

I have three models, which are linked between each other with a has_many :trough association like this:

```
#User model 

has_many :chars_del, :class_name => CharDelegated, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :chars, :through => :chars_del

#CharDelegated model
#has a field owner:integer

belongs_to :char
belongs_to :user

#Char model
#has fields name:string

has_many :chars_del, :class_name => CharDelegated
has_many :users, :through => :chars_del
```

What I need to do is I need to search from a User Record to find all the Chars that the particular user ownes (:owner field is true) ordered by name. I have been stuck with this for a couple hours now, so I believe that I could have missed a very simple answer... But nothing that I have tried so far did work even a bit.

**UPDATE**
found something that works:

```
user.chars.where(:char_delegateds => {:owner => 1}).order('name')
```

don't know why the :chars_del gave an error, but the full table name did the job.

Andrew, your answer works well too and is a little faster on the database, thans alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does

```
user.chars.order('name')
```

not work? (Given `user` is a single `User` instance.)

#### Edit

Given your new information:

```
CharDelegated.where(user_id: user.id, owner: true).map(&:char)
```

should work.

Comment: It does, but it does not consider the value in the middle model record. That is the real problem.

Comment: Nowhere in your description do you mention that, nor *how* that intermediate record should be involved. You state you want all the `Char`s belonging to the `user`, ordered by `name`. My code does exactly that. (You seem to have made an edit that wasn't there when I originally looked at this question, but you state `owner` should be `true`, and yet it is an `integer`.)

Comment: It does not make a difference in the case if it is integer or boolean. I know I have formulated the case ambiguously at first, so I made a correction to the question state. But thank you nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example you don't need to search through the middle table but if you want to see an example of how to use the joining table and search through it for a more complex scenario you can do it this way.

@char = Char.all(:include => :users, :conditions => ["char_delegated.user_id in (?)", user_id]).order('name')